# Avoid warnings and errors for button that opens hyperlinked cell

Tags: excel, vba, button, hyperlink, excel-2007

I have the following code assigned to a button in an excel worksheet.

```
Sub Hyperlink()

Worksheets("Sheet Name").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Hyperlinks(1).Follow

End Sub
```

When the button is clicked, excel will open the active row's attached file. This works fine as long as there is a hyperlink in the active row and the user clicks OK when the warning window pops up.

If possible, How can I:

1. Avoid the warning to open the hyperlinked file?
2. Avoid, disable, or customize the following error messages.

   1. Empty row or no hyperlinked file.

      - (Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.)
   2. Clicking cancel when there is a hyperlinked file.

      - (Run-time error '-24147467260 (80004004)': The hyperlink cannot be followed to the destination.)

[Here are screenshots of the pop-up messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roSKF.jpg)

Thank You.

I also found a way to disable hyperlink warnings [here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925757)
Although, I do not want to do this for every user of the workbook...

Comment: what would you prefer to do if there is no hyperlink or the link can't be followed instead? you could on error resume next, unless there is other code in the sub.

Comment: @datatoo I suppose a message of some sort to let the user know that there is no hyperlink. And there is no other code for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display.Alerts=False will not work, otherwise any bad guy could turn off warnings. This might work for you partially.

```
Sub Hyperlink()
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Sheet Name").Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Hyperlinks(1).Follow
If Error <> "" Then MsgBox ("Nowhere to go, Nothing to see")
End Sub
```